# Pointer madness, I just can't figure it out

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have a pointer problem which I don't understand, I hope you can help me.

```
int main()
{
    int tab[] = {1,2,3};
    int *ptr;
    ptr=tab; // this is where my doubt lies
    cout << &ptr << "," << ptr << "," << *ptr << "," << &tab << "," << tab << "," << *tab << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

to put the pointer pointing to what you want shouldn't you do, for example ptr=&something ??
If someone could explain it to me I appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C arrays decay into pointers whenever they can. With the line

```
ptr=tab;
```

you might encounter similar behavior to

```
ptr=&tab;
```

but the types are different: in the first case you're asking for an int pointer, in the latter you're asking for a pointer to an array of ints with a specific type.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays can decay into pointers to their first element, so when you do this:

```
ptr=tab;
```

`tab` in the RHS decays to an `int*` pointing to the first element of array `tab`. So `ptr` now points to that element.

Answer (score 2):

In C (i think maybe the same applies to C++) when an array name is used by itself, in most circumstances (*) it gets converted to a pointer to its first element.

The two lines below are effectively the same; the first has an implicit conversion

```
ptr = tab;
ptr = &(tab[0]);
```

(*) the exceptions to this rule are when the array is used as operand to the `sizeof` operator (`sizeof tab`) or "address of" operator (`&tab`)

Comment: The second one has an implicit conversion too, because the subscript operator is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. So `ptr = &(tab[0]);` is precisely equivalent to `ptr = &(*(tab + 0));`, where `tab` again decays into a pointer before `0` is added to this pointer... Of course, that last form is precisely equivalent to `ptr = tab + 0;`, which is again precisely equivalent to `ptr = tab;`...